# Subscription return empty array only after first initialisation

Tags: angular

I have a subscription on a array which should be reseted when an event is triggered but when the event is triggered my composent isn't because the array is empty.

My code look like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.listUnstagedFilesSubscription = this.rightPanelService.listUnstagedFilesSubject.subscribe(
      (listUnstagedFiles: any) => {
        this.listUnstagedFiles = listUnstagedFiles;
        this.setUnstageTree(listUnstagedFiles);
      });
    this.rightPanelService.emitListUnstagedFilesSubject();
  }
```

And the setUnstageTree will use 'listUnstagedFiles' to fill another array which is then used to display my component.

The problem is that i don't know why it doesn't work since the component always work at before the event is triggered and it work again if i force the component to reload by calling the function ngOnInit() somewhere

Here's the code which call the subscribe

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class RightPanelService {
  isView: Boolean;
  isViewSubject = new Subject<Boolean>();
  listUnstagedFiles: any[];
  listUnstagedFilesSubject: Subject<any[]>;
  listStagedFiles: any[];
  listStagedFilesSubject: Subject<any[]>;
  commitHash: String;
  commitHashSubject: Subject<String>;

  constructor() {
    this.commitHashSubject = new Subject<String>();
    this.isViewSubject = new Subject<Boolean>();
    this.isView = true;
    this.emitIsViewSubject();
    this.listUnstagedFilesSubject = new Subject<any[]>();
    this.listStagedFilesSubject = new Subject<any[]>();
  }

  emitIsViewSubject() {
    this.isViewSubject.next(this.isView);
  }

  emitListUnstagedFilesSubject() {
    this.listUnstagedFilesSubject.next(this.listUnstagedFiles);
  }

  emitListStagedFilesSubject() {
    this.listStagedFilesSubject.next(this.listStagedFiles);
  }

  setView(view: boolean) {
    this.isView = view;
    this.emitIsViewSubject();
  }

  setListFileCommit(listUnstagedFiles: any[], listStagedFiles: any[]) {
    this.listUnstagedFiles = listUnstagedFiles;
    this.listStagedFiles = listStagedFiles;
    this.emitListUnstagedFilesSubject();
    this.emitListStagedFilesSubject();
  }

  emitCommitHashSubject() {
    this.commitHashSubject.next(this.commitHash);
  }


  setCommitHash(hash: String) {
    this.commitHash = hash;
    this.emitCommitHashSubject();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you think should re-trigger the listUnstagedFilesSubject?

Comment: Can you show the rightPanelService ?

Comment: I've added the whole class

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my own problem, i wasn't waiting for an async function and my variable wasn't set to generate my array